# Hibernate - Mapping a ManyToMany Join Table With Unique Key

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have tables User, Roles, Groups and a join table GroupRoles. A user can have many Roles (some of which are not group specific), and a Group can have many roles. Since Roles can be group related I need to associate a groupID with them and hence GroupRoles has a unique key of userID, groupID and roleID. I need userID as part of the key as I need to know what Roles are associated to a user. In hibernate is mapping a unique key like this the same as mapping a composite key, where I would have something along the lines of

```
@Embeddable
public class GroupRoleKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="userID")
    private Long userID;

    @Column(name="groupID")
    private Long groupID;

    @Column(name="roleID")
    private Long roleID;

    protected GroupRoleKey(){}

    public GroupRoleKey(Long userID, Long roleID, Long groupID) {
        this.userID = userID;
        this.roleID = roleID;
        this.groupID = groupID
    }
```

Honestly I'm not sure if this is even the best way to represent the User - Role - Group relation, any advice would be appreciated. I need to display a Users Roles within each group they belong to, for example I may want to display Bob's Roles Admin and Teacher for Group 1 and role Group Admin for group 2. I need to know which roles correspond to what group and what roles correspond to what user.

EDIT:

Group Entity:

```
@Table(name="FocusGroups")
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "groupID")
public class Group {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long groupID;
    private String groupName;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "GroupMembers",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "groupID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "userID"))
    private Set<User> groupMembers = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "GroupRoles",
            joinColumns =
                @JoinColumn(
                name = "groupID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "roleID"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name="frameworkID", nullable = true)
    private Framework framework;

    public Group(){}

    public Group(String groupName, Set<User> groupMembers, Framework framework) {
        this.groupName = groupName;
        this.groupMembers = groupMembers;
        this.framework = framework;
    }

    public Long getGroupID() {
        return groupID;
    }

    public void setGroupID(Long groupID) {
        this.groupID = groupID;
    }

    public String getGroupName() {
        return groupName;
    }

    public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
        this.groupName = groupName;
    }

    public Set<User> getGroupMembers() {
        return groupMembers;
    }

    public void setGroupMembers(Set<User> groupMembers) {
        this.groupMembers = groupMembers;
    }

    public void addMembers(Set<User> groupMembers){
        this.groupMembers.addAll(groupMembers);
    }

    public void addMember(User groupMember){
        this.groupMembers.add(groupMember);
    }

    public String groupMembersToString(){
        String out = "";
        int count = 0;
        if(groupMembers.size() > 0){
            for(User user: groupMembers){
                if(count >= 1){
                    out += ", ";
                }
                out += user.getUsername();
                count++;
            }
        }else{
            out = "No members";
        }
        return out;
    }

    public boolean hasMember(String groupMemberName) {
        for (User member : this.groupMembers) {
            if (member.getUsername().equals(groupMemberName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public User getGroupMember(String groupMemberName){
        for(User member: this.groupMembers){
            if(member.getUsername().equals(groupMemberName)){
                return member;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Framework getFramework() {
        return framework;
    }

    public void setFramework(Framework framework) {
        this.framework = framework;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

Role:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Roles")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long roleID;

    private String roleName;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "GroupRoles",
            joinColumns =
            @JoinColumn(
                    name = "roleID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "groupID", nullable = true))
    private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<>();

    protected Role(){}

    public Role(String roleName){
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return roleID;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.roleID = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return roleName;
    }

    public void setName(String roleName) {
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }
}
```

User:

```
@Table(name="Users")
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
        @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
                name = "userRating",
                procedureName = "CalculateUserRating",
                parameters = {
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(
                                name = "userID",
                                type = Long.class,
                                mode = ParameterMode.IN),
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(
                                name = "focusID",
                                type = Long.class,
                                mode = ParameterMode.IN),
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(
                                name = "userRating",
                                type = BigDecimal.class,
                                mode = ParameterMode.OUT)
                })
})
//store a base rating?
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userID;

    @Column(name = "userHashedPassword")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "userName")
    private String userName;
    @Column(name = "userEmail")
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "GroupMembers",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "userID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "groupID"))
    private Set<Group> usersGroups = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "UserRoles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "userID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "roleID"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Rating> ratings;

    protected User(){}

    public User(String userHashedPassword, String userName, String email, Set<Role> roles){
        this.password = userHashedPassword;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.email = email;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public User(String userName, String userHashedPassword){
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = userHashedPassword;
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setId(Long userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getPassword(){
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password){
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUsername(String name) {
        this.userName = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public Set<Rating> getRatings() {
        return ratings;
    }

    public void setRatings(Set<Rating> ratings) {
        this.ratings = ratings;
    }

    public String rolesToString(){
        String outputRoles = "";
        int count = 0;
        for(Role role: roles){
            if(count >= 1){
                outputRoles += ", ";
            }
            outputRoles += role.getName();
            count++;
        }
        return outputRoles;
    }

    public void removeRole(Role role){
        this.roles.remove(role);
    }

    public Set<Group> getGroups() {
        return usersGroups;
    }

    public void addGroup(Group group) {
        this.usersGroups.add(group);
    }

    public void addGroups(Set<Group> groups) {
        this.usersGroups.addAll(groups);
    }

    public Set<Group> getUsersGroups() {
        return usersGroups;
    }

    public void setUsersGroups(Set<Group> usersGroups) {
        this.usersGroups = usersGroups;
    }

    public String groupsToString(){
        String outputGroups = "";
        int count = 0;
        if(usersGroups.size() > 0){
            for(Group group: usersGroups){
                if(count >= 1){
                    outputGroups += ", ";
                }
                outputGroups += group.getGroupName();
                count++;
            }
        }else{
            outputGroups = "None";
        }
        return outputGroups;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us more details about your requirement? Please provide all the entity class along with their mapping. And do you really need role and group together. You can use any one of them (i.e. role/group)

Comment: @Numery I've adjusted my question accordingly